# How frequently data should be saved if form is very large

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a doubt on saving data in database using ajax. (I can do this part). My problem is I have a very large form which is nested( I can't change it). Large form in terms of input fields which need to be saved in data approx 100 fields. new field may open it depends on users selected options.

ex- suppose one question is like which game you play. In multi select drop down if he selects one game than next questions would be how frequently you play this game .on which day which time and many more. Each game may have different set of question.

Now my problem is how to save this data in database. Should I save it after user click submit or should I save it in between user is feeling data. so that he refresh the data it can have his data filled .

How frequently should I send Ajax request for saving data and how to get the data from the fields which are newly field and how I should save it in Rails.
I know about update.attributes

please help me or give some suggestions how should I do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you live edit or only on save has mostly user expierence questions.

But if you are frequently saving (like an autosave) and are worried about the size (100 normal columns might be OK anyway, allthough large text or blobs less so) then what you want to do fairly simply is only save the fields that have actually changed.

There are many ways to implement this in JavaScript. You might just save each input when the user finishes editing it (e.g. the input loosing focus) or you might save based on a timer and track the changed fields since last save.

Then have your JavaScript just include those fields in its AJAX request (`PATCH` migh be a good method to use). Rails should then only try to save the attributes on the object that you changed (via `update_attributes`, or `save` on the ActiveRecord). If you want to also optimise out the `SELECT`, use `update` or `update_all` on the class. e.g. ends up like:

```
MyBigRecord.update(id, title: "My new title")
```

You can easily use the normal strong parameters here, which only includes those actually present in `params`.

```
MyBigRecord.update(id, params.require(:my_big_record).permit(:title, :author, :etc))
```

If you need to deal with sub objects then you may need some special handling, but the idea is the same). A little bit of logic can also do the initial `create` on demand, allthough your JavaScript then recieve the `id` to use for future saves.